# Event Handler OnItemCommand with TextBox control

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have Repeater that contains a TextBox and a LinkButton. When the LinkButton is clicked, I need to grab the TextBox.Text and do stuff …

Using the EVENT **Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)** I am able to get the value of the TextBox using TextBox tx = e.Item.FindControl("txCode") as TextBox

However

Using the EVENT **Repeater1_ItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)** I am NOT getting anything back. The TextBox is empty.

How can I get the text/content from the TextBox using 'OnItemCommand'?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" onitemdatabound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>                    
        <asp:TextBox ID="txCode" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:LinkButton CommandName="verifyCode" ID="lbCode" runat="server">Submit<asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**I am able to get the TextBox Value below**

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tx = e.Item.FindControl("txCode") as TextBox;
    string myText = tx.Text; '<--- working
}
```

**I am NOT able to get the TextBox Value below**

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "verifyCode")
    {
        TextBox tx = e.Item.FindControl("txCode") as TextBox;
        string myText = tx.Text;  '<--- NOT working
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged to see if this event is raised? Maybe you've missed to check for `!IsPostBack` in Page_Load. Bind the repeater not on postbacks to it's DataSource.

Comment: if(!IsPostBack) - Damm <-- worked!  Thanks @Tim Schmelter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not bind your `Repeater` to it's `DataSource` on every postback. Otherwise ViewState cannot be reloaded correctly what causes issues like this.

So always check the [`IsPostBack` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) in Page_Load when [ViewState](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx) is enabled([`EnableViewState=true`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.enableviewstate.aspx)):

```
if(!IsPostBack)BindRepeaterToDataSource();
```